# A necessary condition to $F'(x)=f(x)$ for a continuous function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

> **Theorem:**  Consider ,
>
> $$F(x)=\int_a^xf(t)\,dt$$
>
> If the function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is continuous then , $F(x)$ is differentiable and $F'(x)=f(x).$

I know that the **continuity** condition of $f$ is **sufficient** condition.

That means there exists a discontinuous function $f$ for which this $F'(x)=f(x)$.

**My Question:**

Does there exist a **necessary** condition for this ?

$$OR$$

After imposing which extra condition on $f$  it is necessary that $F'(x)=f(x)$ ?

Comment: well if $f$ has a jump discontinuity in $c\in[a,b]$ then $F$ will not be differentiable in $c$ (right derivative different from left derivative). If $f$ has a removable discontinuity then $F$ will be differentiable but will disagree with $f$ in $c$ (basically you're integrating the function with the discontinuity removed). Are you asking for $F'(x)=f(x)\text{ a.e. } x \in [a,b]$?

Comment: I don't say about discontinuity.....

Comment: You said "there exists a discontinuous function $f$ for which this $F'(x)=f(x)$". Was this part of the question?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$To speak of "the converse" of the theorem (as currently written) is ambiguous, because

1. It's not specified whether $x$ refers to a single number ("if $f$ is continuous at $x$, then $F$ is differentiable at $x$...") or a general number ("for all $x$ in $(a, b)$...");
2. No hypotheses for $f$ have been given before the definition of $F$.

The first omission is relatively minor; we can alway focus attention at one point. But the second (failure to specify "standing hypotheses" about $f$) is disastrous in terms of reading meaning into the notion of a "converse". (The linguistic morals include: "Only speak of a converse when you have a well-formed logical implication", and "avoid pronouns such as *this* and *it*, particularly when they refer to a logical proposition''. Pronouns already induce plenty of confusion when they refer to some mathematical object in situations with several objects under discussion.)

---

Based on context gleaned from the precise wording of the question and from subsequent comments, I assume the following wording: Let $a < b$ be real numbers, $f:[a, b] \to \Reals$ a Riemann integrable function, and $F:[a, b] \to \Reals$ the function defined by
$$
F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t)\, dt.
$$

**Theorem**: If $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, then $F$ is differentiable on $(a, b)$, and $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in $[a, b]$ (with "differentiability" being one-sided at the endpoints).

Consequently, I assume "the converse" reads: If $F$ is differentiable on $[a, b]$ and if $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in $[a, b]$, then $f$ is continuous.

The converse is false. To see why, pick your favorite differentiable (but not continuously-differentiable) function, namely
$$
F(x) = \begin{cases}
  x^{2} \sin(1/x) & x \neq 0, \\
  0 & x = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
The (discontinuous) derivative
$$
F'(x) = \begin{cases}
  2x\sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x) & x \neq 0, \\
  0 & x = 0,
\end{cases}
$$
is bounded and continuous everywhere except $0$, so $f = F'$ is Riemann integrable on an arbitrary closed (bounded) interval.

To be completely explicit, let $[a, b] = [0, 1]$, and put
$$
f(t) = \begin{cases}
  2t\sin(1/t) - \cos(1/t) & 0 < t \leq 1, \\
  0 & t = 0,
\end{cases}\qquad
F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(t)\, dt =  \begin{cases}
  x^{2} \sin(1/x) & x \neq 0, \\
  0 & x = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
The function $F$ is differentiable on $[0, 1]$ and $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in $[0, 1]$, but $f$ is not continuous. (It should be equally clear we can arrange worse behavior, e.g. $f$ having a dense set of discontinuities.)

The preceding is an attempt to address the question in the comment. As to the questions in the body of the post:

- "Is there a **necessary** condition for this?" Presumably the intended question reads "Is there a (non-vacuous) condition on $F$ or $F'$ guaranteeing $f = F'$ is continuous?" Modulo interpretation, "no". Continuity of $f$ is equivalent to...continuity of $F' = f$.
- "After imposing extra condition[s] on $f$ is it necessary (i.e., logically implied) that $F' = f$?" As demonstrated by the example, that's tricky. In detail, let $c$ be a non-zero real number, and define
  $$
  g(t) = \begin{cases}
    2t\sin(1/t) - \cos(1/t) & 0 < t \leq 1, \\
    c & t = 0.
  \end{cases}
  $$
  If $G$ denotes the definite integral of $g$ from $0$, then $F = G$, but of course $G'(0) = 0 \neq c = g(0)$.

Philosophically, the definite integral "knows the correct value of $G'(0)$" even though $G'$ is discontinuous. Any extra condition on $f$ has to detect this type of behavior.

To put it more bluntly, suppose you came across the question: Suppose $g(t) = 2t\sin(1/t) - \cos(1/t)$ for $t > 0$. What is the value of $g(0)$? (I can almost guarantee that if this were posted on Math.SE, there'd be a flame-fest, because there are infinitely many answers under the stated conditions.) According to the definite integral / antiderivative, however, there is a *unique "correct" answer*, $g(0) = 0$. (!) The point is, any extra condition imposed on $g$ has to be able to give this answer. Offhand, I don't see any non-trivial condition, i.e., any condition other than "Integrate, differentiate the integral, and see if the values match".

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$. Then the function $$F(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f(t)\,dt$$ is known to be continuous and of bounded variation on $[a, b]$. Apart from these properties of $F$ it is possible to ensure differentiability of $F$ at points where $f$ is continuous.

Another point to note is that since $F(x)$ is of bounded variation it possesses a derivative *almost everywhere* i.e. $F$ is differentiable on $[a, b] - E_{1}$ where $E_{1}$ is a subset of $[a, b]$ of measure zero. Similarly since $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$, it follows that $f$ is continuous almost everywhere on $[a, b]$ so that there is a subset $E_{2}$ of $[a, b]$ of measure zero such that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b] - E_{2}$.

Since $E = E_{1} \cup E_{2}$ is also of measure zero, it follows that $F'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b] - E$. Thus the relation $F'(x) = f(x)$ holds almost everywhere in $[a, b]$.

Also note that $E_{1} \subseteq E_{2}$. I suspect there are examples where $E_{1} \subset E_{2}$ but I don't have an example right now with me.

Comment: "However the relation F′(x)=f(x) will hold only at the points where f is continuous." That's not true, there are counterexamples.

Comment: @zhw.: agree... continuity of $f$ will guarantee that $F$ is differentiable at that point. But not the other way. Will update the answer.

Comment: My question is: Write down such a **condition**  on $f$ such that if $f$ does not satisfy that condition then $F'(x)\not =f(x)$..I don't know either such a condition exists or NOT..

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: Finding such a condition is effectively trying to figure out a criteria to distinguish the cases when $E_{1} = E_{2}$ and when $E_{1} \subset E_{2}$ in my answer. I am not aware of such a condition.